# connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "" with external database azure

Tags: django, postgresql, azure

I have a django docker container running. And I try to connect with the azure postgres db.

But when I log in in the admin panel from django, I get this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/login/
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "welzijn"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "0.0.145.0", user "welzijn", database "welzijn", no encryption
```

And I thought that I had the solution. Because a lot of resources suggest that you have to edit the pg_hba file and the postgresql file. So I did that:

pgb_hba:

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 scram-sha-256
```

And postgresql:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I rebooted the machine. But it seems that it didn't solve the issue. I still get this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/login/
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "welzijn"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "0.0.145.0", user "welzijn", database "welzijn", no encryption
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 4.2.4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "welzijn"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "85.148.145.211", user "welzijn", database "welzijn", no encryption
Exception Location: /py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py, line 122, in connect
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.sites.login
Python Executable:  /py/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.9
Python Path:    
['/usr/src/app',
 '/py/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 23 Aug 2023 11:47:25 +0200
```

Second thing I tried was in azure the setting `require_secure_transport` turned off
Also, not solved the issue.

So I am really stuck on this issue

This is the .env.prod file I am using in the docker-compose-deploy.yml file:

```
DEBUG=0
SECRET_KEY="+)d)1o(&r3+24)x#i^bk8p8r)@jl_q2=%usxw="
DB_NAME="welzijn"
DB_USER="welzijn"
DB_PASSWORD="password"
DB_HOST="db-wellzijn-nvwa.postgres.database.azure.com"
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1] 0.0.0.0
```

And this is my docker-compose-deploy.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    restart: always

    command: gunicorn Welzijn.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod

  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/staticfiles

volumes:
  static-data:
```

Question: how to resolve the issue: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host ...

Comment: That message shows two problems.  The main problem is the password problem, the other one is just a distraction. Look in the db server log file for more info about the password problem.

Comment: @jjanes. Thank you for you reply . I thought also there is something wrong with the password. But that is not the case. Because in pgadmin4 I connect to the azure database with the password. And I can connect to the azure database. So it is a correct password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the authentication for the database you might have allowed Azure active directory authentication only and that could be the reason that the standalone users (Postgres authentication) are not working.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh-MSFT.Oke, that is strange. Because when I run the dcoker-compose file then I can connect with the azure databae. But when I run the docker-compose-deploy file I can't. But what I have to change then?

Comment: @ShaktiSingh-MSFT.I have by Authenticate. the first option enabled: PostgreSQL authentication only

Comment: This is really strange. Because from pgAdmin I can connect to the Azure database.